# From Now() to Current_timestamp in Postgresql

Tags: sql, datetime, postgresql

In mysql I am able to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE auth_user.lastactivity > NOW() - 100
```

now in postgresql I am using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE auth_user.lastactivity > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 100
```

but I get this error:

```
operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - integer
```

How can I resolve ?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Use an interval instead of an integer:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE auth_user.lastactivity > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '100 days'
```

Answer (score 37):

You can also use `now()` in Postgres. The problem is you can't add/subtract integers from `timestamp` or `timestamptz`. You can either do as Mark Byers suggests and subtract an interval, or use the `date` type which does allow you to add/subtract integers

```
SELECT now()::date + 100 AS date1, current_date - 100 AS date2
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but: INTERVAL makes it obvious which unit you are working in when you perform date math. For example, it is non-obvious which future instant in time `now()::date + 100` represents. Is there a case where integer math is necessary over INTERVAL math?

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example ...

```
select * from tablename where to_char(added_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  = to_char( now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
```

added_time is a column name which I converted to char for match

Comment: That will work very slow because it calculate operation on each row. So it can't use index on plain `added_time` column. Off course you may create functional index said on `to_char(added_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` but it seems overhead in that situation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what the MySQL docs say about `NOW()`:

> Returns the current date and time as a value in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` or
> `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format,
> depending on whether the function is
> used in a string or numeric context.
> The value is expressed in the current
> time zone.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
        -> '2007-12-15 23:50:26'
mysql> SELECT NOW() + 0;
        -> 20071215235026.000000
```

Now, you can certainly reduce your smart date to something less...

```
SELECT (
 date_part('year', NOW())::text
 || date_part('month', NOW())::text
 || date_part('day', NOW())::text
 || date_part('hour', NOW())::text
 || date_part('minute', NOW())::text
 || date_part('second', NOW())::text
)::float8 + foo;
```

But, that would be a really bad idea, what you need to understand is that times and dates are not stupid unformated numbers, they are their [own type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) with their [own set of functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) and [operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE)

So the MySQL time essentially lets you treat `NOW()` as a dumber type, or it overrides `+` to make a presumption that I can't find in the MySQL docs. Eitherway, you probably want to look at the `date` and `interval` types in pg.

Answer (score -3):

```
select * from table where column_date > now()- INTERVAL '6 hours';
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, please also provide a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.