# NodeJS + PostgreSQL: INSERT has more target columns than expressions

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'd like to `INSERT` the current timestamp with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`on each new user registration. The column number equal the number of parameters in `VALUES`. Yet I get `INSERT has more target columns than expressions`. Using the `node-postgres` npm module as a controller.

```
                         //Just 3 parameters, timestamp is hardcoded in the query
exports.create = function (username, email, password) {
    DB.connect(connection, function (err, client, done) {
        var query = client.query(

    //4 columns 
    "INSERT INTO users (username, email, userpass, datecreated) VALUES" +
    //4 parameters
    "(" + "'" + username + "'" + "," + "'" + email + "'" + "," + "'" + password + "'" + "'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')");
        query.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log("query returned an " + error);
        });
        query.on('row', function (row, result) {
            result.addRow(row);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Seems to me you are passing in the string value of Current_Timestamp; not calling the function current_timestamp. Perhaps you need to remove the tics around it.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993468/from-now-to-current-timestamp-in-postgresql) how it's not in tics?

Comment: Removing the single quotes around it returns `syntax error at or near CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: I would write the entire string to a variable, then display the results of the variable.  My guess is you have a syntax error somewhere else then.... ***Like missing comma after password*** in addition to the bad tics around current_timestamp

Comment: **Do not use this code**. It's terribly insecure and will cause hard to debug database errors with some user input too. Read about SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing comma after password and no tics around current_Timestamp

```
"INSERT INTO users (username, email, userpass, datecreated) VALUES" +
    //4 parameters
    "(" + "'" + username + "'" + "," + "'" + email + "'" + "," + "'" + password + "," + "'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
```

--- While this may have been the accepted answer addressing the immediate issue, ***I highly recommend Craig and Lars answers be evaluated***.  Use of Parameters is a far better long term approach as it is more secure; actually easier to code once you understand how, and the correct modern paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was based on older provided code, it isn't accurate anymore so I removed it.

You're missing a comma `,` between `password` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I'd advise you to use [parameterized queries](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements) instead of building them yourself like this.

Comment: There is a `datecreated` column for the purpose ^

Comment: + for going above and beyond on the answer, not just addressing the immediate issue.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> `"(" + "'" + username + "'" + "," + "'" + email + "'" + "," + "'" + password + "'" + "'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')"`
> ```

Nonononono!

That is not how you pass parameters, and may bewhy you're having problems. (xQbert points out you're also missing a comma).

Imagine if I entered the username

```
');--DROP TABLE users;--
```

Splat. [There goes your application](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Use [*parameterized queries*](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Prepared-Statements) by *binding* parameters to *placeholders*. This is often called "prepared statements" though they're really something different.

e.g.

```
client.query(
    "INSERT INTO users (username, email, userpass, datecreated) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, current_timestamp)",
    [username, email, password])
```

Your problem will go away.

[Now read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Note that this *isn't just a security problem*, it's also a *bug* that will cause errors even from non-malicious users. I enter a nice secure looking password like `94/Ql@$'B'wC`. Boom, your app falls over with a database error.

Comment: + for going above and beyond on the answer, not just addressing the immediate issue.

Comment: It's constantly frustrating to me that obvious SQL injection holes keep getting produced by new programmers. There must be some way to improve driver docs, languages, etc. People just keep doing it, and SQL-injection-whack-a-mole isn't a good path to secure applications. Augh. I try to raise the issue whenever I see it arise in the hopes that more people will search for errors, find these sorts of answers, and realise "um, so my whole app is horrifically insecure and buggy? Better fix that then."